# return single column data in List<string> of Child table

Tags: c#, string, list, entity-framework, linq

I have two table with PK & FK combination.

```
Table: Client
int ID
nvarchar(max) ClientName
nvarchar(max) Address

Table ClientSocial
int client_ID
nvarchar(max) FB_LINK
nvarchar(max) TWITTER_LINK
```

I want to get "FB_LINK" column in `List<string>`. here is thing I tried

```
var lientList= new Client();
clientList= db.Clients.Where(ab=> ab.Id==1).Select(ab=> new NewModel {
ClientName= ab.ClientName,

FacebookLinks= new List<string>
{
ab.ClientSocials.ToList(); // Here I need to change
//Things I tried
// ab.ClientSocials.Select(cs => cs.FB_LINK).ToList()
// ab.ClientSocials.Where(.. Some Condition..).Select(cs => cs.FB_LINK).ToList()
// If I use ToString() at end it works but no LIST
// ab.ClientSocials.Where(.. Some Condition..).Select(cs => cs.FB_LINK).ToList().ToString()
}
}).single();
```

If you want, here is NewModel Class

```
NewModel Class
{
    public string clientName {get; set; }
    public List<string> FacebookLinks { get; set; }
}
```

I tried but I am not getting data from child table in list.

Thank you in advance

Comment: what is the type of FacebookLinks is it of type list  or string?

Comment: Its List<string> FacebookLinks { get; set; }

Comment: do you have one to many links for client->FB Links. i suspect you are getting only one FB link and you are trying to assign to List . thats why you are getting Error cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string

Comment: Yes, I have one to many relation. And it is correct, in Table  I am having only one link as data, and that I am assigning to List. What I need to do.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Select`.

```
clientList= db.Clients
     .Where(ab => ab.Id==1)
     .Select(ab => new NewModel 
      {
         ClientName= ab.ClientName,  
         FacebookLinks= ab.ClientSocials.Select(cs => cs.FB_LINK).ToList()
      }).Single();
```

Comment: Error is::::      Error CS1503 cannot convert from System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' to 'string'

Comment: Put the `NewModel` class in your question. What is `FacebookLinks`?

Comment: @PruthvirajMohite and why do you have a `.Single()` at the end when you are assigning to a `clientList`? Do you want just one or all of them?

Comment: I added how FacebookLinks field look in NewModel Class

Comment: Yup.. Its just one of them

Comment: @PruthvirajMohite Did you try it exactly as I wrote or do you still have that extra `new List<string> { ...}` bit in there.